# Very long loadtime php curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a site for my battlefield 1 clan, on one of the pages i'd like to display our team and some of their stats.

[This](https://trnbattlefield.docs.apiary.io/#reference) API allows me to request just what I need, I decide to use php curl requests to get this data on my site. It all works perfectly fine, but it is super slow, sometimes it even reaches the 30s max of php.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$data = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM bfplayers");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
$psnid = $row['psnid'];


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://battlefieldtracker.com/bf1/api/Stats/BasicStats?platform=2&displayName=".$psnid);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$headers = [
    'TRN-Api-Key: MYKEY',
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response, true);

print($result['profile']['displayName']);
    }
?>
```

I have no idea why it's going this slow, is it because I am using xamp on localhost or because the requests are going through a loop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the API allow you to query multiple players at once? That way you'd only need to make one request, and cut down on the time significantly.

Comment: You're making a curl request for each row in your table. I don't know how many that is, but that could obviously get out of control pretty quickly.  Especially since you create and destroy the curl handler each time through the loop.  If you have 30 rows, then obviously it only takes a not-too-unreasonable response time of 1 second from the remote site to hit a total of 30 seconds.

Comment: Problem can come from multiple request at very short time you are doing curl inside while loop. It’s not the best way but u can try to set sleep(0.5) before print and try again

Comment: i dont think any one has mentioned caching .. so cache locally if you hit the API often and dont need fresh data

Comment: Theres 15 players in the database atm, so thats not too much and I dont think that it's possible to request data from multiple players at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your loop is not optimized in the slightest, i believe if you optimized your loop code, your code could run A LOT faster. you create and delete the curl handle on each iteration, when you could just keep re-using the same curl handle on each player (this would use less cpu and be faster), you don't use compressed transfer (enabling compression would probably make the transfer faster), and most importantly, you run the api calls sequentially, i believe if you did the api requests in parallel, it would load much faster. also, you don't urlencode psnid, that's probably a bug. try this

```
<?php
$cmh = curl_multi_init ();
$curls = array ();
$data = $connection->query ( "SELECT * FROM bfplayers" );

while ( ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $data )) ) {
    $psnid = $row ['psnid'];
    $tmp = array ();
    $tmp [0] = ($ch = curl_init ());
    $tmp [1] = tmpfile ();
    $curls [] = $tmp;
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://battlefieldtracker.com/bf1/api/Stats/BasicStats?platform=2&displayName=" . urlencode ( $psnid ),
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                    'TRN-Api-Key: MYKEY' 
            ),
            CURLOPT_FILE => $tmp [1] 
    ) );
    curl_multi_add_handle ( $cmh, $ch );
    curl_multi_exec ( $cmh, $active );
}
do {
    do {
        $ret = curl_multi_exec ( $cmh, $active );
    } while ( $ret == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );
    curl_multi_select ( $cmh, 1 );
} while ( $active );
foreach ( $curls as $curr ) {
    fseek ( $curr [1], 0, SEEK_SET ); // https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268
    $response = stream_get_contents ( $curr [1] );
    $result = json_decode ( $response,true );
    print ($result ['profile'] ['displayName']) ;
}
// the rest is just cleanup, the client shouldn't have to wait for this
// OPTIMIZEME: apache version of fastcgi_finish_request() ?
if (is_callable ( 'fastcgi_finish_request' )) {
    fastcgi_finish_request ();
}
foreach ( $curls as $curr ) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle ( $cmh, $curr [0] );
    curl_close ( $curr [0] );
    fclose ( $curr [1] );
}
curl_multi_close ( $cmh );
```

- it runs all api calls in parallel, and use transfer compression (CURLOPT_ENCODING), and runs api requests in parallel with downloading results from the db, and it tries to disconnect the client before running cleanup routines, it will probably run much faster.

also, if mysqli_fetch_assoc() are causing slow roundtrips to your db, it would probably be even faster to replace it with mysqli_fetch_all()

also, something that would probably be much faster than this, would be to have a cronjob run every minute (or every 10 seconds?) that caches the results, and show a cached result to the client. (even if the api calls lags, the client pageload wouldn't be affected at all.)

Comment: Thank you very much, at first your code gave me this error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. But I fixed that by setting the second parameter of json_decode  to true

Comment: @CheapGamer mildly curious, how much faster is it? did you time the old code vs the new code?

Comment: My browser now loads the page in less than 2 seconds, great improvement i'd say

Comment: @CheapGamer and previously?

Comment: Somewhere around 17 seconds, if it loaded at all